# Gibt es in der deutschen Sprache das Adverb »endes« oder etwas Ähnliches?

Tags: word-usage

In der deutschen Sprache existiert das Adverb *anfangs*, das dem Adverb *am Anfang* gleichen kann, meine Frage ist, ob das Adverb *endes* oder etwas Ähnliches, das dem Adverb *am Ende* gleichen kann, existiert oder nicht

Comment: Die feststehende Wendung *letzten Endes* ist nicht gemeint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es gibt mehrere Adverbien, die als Gegensatz zu *"anfangs"* gebraucht werden können. Am gebräuchlichsten ist

> schließlich,

daneben gibt es auch noch

> letztlich,
>
> endlich.

Man beachte, dass diese Adverbien ebenso wie *"anfangs"* nur temporal
gebraucht werden, während *"am Anfang"* oder *"am Ende"* auch
Ortsangaben sein können (*"am Anfang/Ende des Zuges"*).

Comment: Je nach gewünschter sprachlicher Nuance auch noch: _zuletzt_ / _letztendlich_ / _zu guter Letzt_ und sicher noch einiges mehr...

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt auch noch...

> Letzen Endes

Wird aber nicht mehr viel verwendet. Meist sagt oder schreibt man stattdessen "letztendlich". "Zu guter Letzt" fällt mir noch ein.

Comment: »Wird aber nicht mehr viel verwendet«? Kann ich nicht bestätigen, diesen Satz.